# What is the Mandarin equivalent of 對 XXX 嚟講?

Tags: mandarin, expressions, cantonese, topolect

In Cantonese, `對我嚟講` more or less means "speaking for myself", for instance, in:

> 對我嚟講，行政長官選舉唔重要。
>
> Speaking for myself, the chief executive election isn't important.

我 can also be replaced with other pronouns: e.g. 我哋，佢，佢哋, or by a noun.

What is an equivalent expression in Mandarin? I have tried searching in Nciku, but the only thing that came up for me that seemed useful was 作为, which doesn't seem to be used in the same capacity - if I've gotten the correct impression, it's not really used in the same capacity.

Comment: I don't know Cantonese, but according to "Speaking for myself", you can get "对我来说", "就我个人而言", etc.

Comment: @songyuanyao: thanks. The first expression sounds similar to what I was aiming for. (I had what was - to me anyway - probably a Cantonese equivalent but either I'd forgotten the Mandarin phrase from lack of usage or something.)

Comment: Maybe you mean "对我来讲"? If try to translate it word by word. And it's same as "对我来说".

Comment: @songyuanyao: yeah, that should be it. I was (earlier) hung up on what the third character was supposed to be in Mandarin which confused me.

Comment: I think it should be "来". According to http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=shqYSiKiLuZ0mIvMhFMN1SgzMMggkyaIM29JRQoTiBZmrdT_umI9BR_7K2k6xyFi, http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E7%B2%B5%E8%AA%9E, http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=k8oAgHFOpl4VoWdjS5C6tDCX5sDdTEknZsOLPNXqicYtwskA371w5pbXL-daCN9K

Answer (score 4):

对X而言:

## Oxford English

> his promise isn't worth a damn to me
> 他的承诺对我而言一文不值